# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured //Cant find application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Error Logs
I saw some solves, but I dont have an application.properties file to change the 'url'

```
2022-04-19 22:26:58.653  WARN 18764 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2022-04-19 22:26:58.655  INFO 18764 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-04-19 22:26:58.682  INFO 18764 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-19 22:26:58.704 ERROR 18764 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I cant understand, why have i got problems with Date Base, when I havent used it yet?
My code java
Maybe i didnt initialize url in pom.xml

```
package springClient;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringClient {
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        SpringApplication.run(SpringClient.class);
    }
}
```

And pom.xml dependencies:
I m using PostgreSQL
Cant understand Maven

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Pls help me to fix this error.
Or if you will find my mistake, pls write how to correct it:)

Comment: The problem is with your maven dependencies. You have to remove `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` or provide the necessarry configuration parameters in your application.properties for connecting to your database, or you can use an embedded database like it is suggested. But for using H2 database you need other maven dependencies too.

Comment: @Gergo, I have removed this dependency, but the Error is the same. If you know, where can I find an application.properties file?

Comment: If you need a file _application.properties_ you would have to create one on your classpath. With the maven setup it has to go into src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to create an application.properties file on the way 'src/main/resources'
And there write

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:\\link\\
spring.datasource.username=\*of your DB*\
spring.datasource.password=\*of your DB*\
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.\*your DB*\.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

remote.server.api=http://localhost:8080/api/
```